# Smalltalk & Garbage Collection

Tags: garbage-collection, smalltalk

Smalltalk has automatic garbage collection right? So, is that to say that I can do something like the following with no unexpected side-affects?

```
transactions := Set new.
transactions add: tran1.
transactions add: tran2.
transactions add: tran3.
transactions add: tran4.
...
transactions add: tran899.
transactions add: tran900.

|||  ~~ Do some stuff ~~  |||

transactions post.
transactions := Set new.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the reference count will go to zero when you reassign the transaction variable, and the previously-referenced object will be cleaned up forthwith.

Comment: There's nothing in the Smalltalk Language Specification that guarantees that an implementation will use a reference counting garbage collector. In fact, all implementations I know use tracing collectors not reference counting ones.

Comment: yes, but in any case, what @ctote asked is if he can do that without problems... and the answer is YES... GC will take care about the old reference in "transactions" and it will keep the new one.

Comment: What is the "post" method? Why is "post" defined for Set? If the post method has side effects that cause the Set to be stored, then it might not be garbage collected.

Comment: That slide show does _not_ say that Smalltalk uses reference counting. It has a slide that shows _explains_ reference counting.